# Confused of Struts populating a page parameter to action member variable

Tags: struts2

Struts web project, there is a query condition in post form

```xml
<input type="text" name="artsianTime" value="16-3-19" readonly="readonly" 
         id="artsianTime" class="Wdate1" style="width: 100px" 
    onclick="WdatePicker({dateFmt:'yyyy-MM-dd'})">
```

and there is a member variable in action

```java
private Date artsianTime = new Date();
public void setArtsianTime(Date artsianTime) {
    System.out.println(this);
    System.out.println(artsianTime);
    this.artsianTime = artsianTime;
}
```

and set a breakpoint in `setArtsianTime`, found when execute query call `setArtsianTime` three times, so I'm very confused why have to call three times, why not just once?

```
com.foo.artisan.web.ArtisanDateQueryAction@6cc039da
Sat Mar 19 00:00:00 CST 2016
com.foo.artisan.web.ArtisanDateQueryAction@6cc039da
Sat Mar 19 00:00:00 CST 2016
com.foo.artisan.web.ArtisanDateQueryAction@6cc039da
Sat Mar 19 00:00:00 CST 2016
```

---

Full stack trace in eclipse debug perspective

first call
[image]

second call
[image]

third call
[image]

---

struts.xml

```xml
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do,action"/>
    <include file="struts-artisan.xml"/>    
</struts>
```

struts-artisan.xml

```xml
<package name="artisan" namespace="/artisan" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="basicStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="createSession" />
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">  
            <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>  
            <param name="exception.logLevel">error</param>  
        </interceptor-ref>  
        <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
        <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
        <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
        <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
        <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
        <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
        <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
        <interceptor-ref name="params" />
        <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
        <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="exception">
            <param name="logEnabled">true</param>
            <param name="logLevel">warn</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
    <default-action-ref name="notFound" />
<global-results>
    <result name="ERROR">/exception.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/exception.jsp</result>
    <result name="INPUT">/input_exception.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/input_exception.jsp</result>
    <result name="INDEX_PAGE">/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="no_priviledge">/no_priviledge.jsp</result>
    <result name="no_login">/no_login.jsp</result>
</global-results>

<action name="artisanDateQueryAction" class="artisanDateQueryAction">
    <result name="query_work_success">/adminsys/artisan/search_artisan_work.jsp</result>
    <result name="artisan_date_list">/adminsys/artisan/date/artisan_date_list.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
```

Comment: May be I will tell you if you post full stacktraces for all cases.

Comment: Hi @RomanC is image ok?

Comment: Image is ok, but on SO better to post text instead of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm very confused why have to call **three** times, why not just **once**?

Well, I'm not sure about your *second* call, but I can explain the *first* and the *third* ones:

As configured in the [struts-default.xml](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-defaultxml.html), the `defaultStack` is:

```xml
    <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="datetime"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="validation">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
    </interceptor-stack>
```

And since you're including the `defaultStack` into your Stack, you have most of the interceptors doubled. This is what you really are using to intercept your actions:

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="basicStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="createSession" />

    <!-- DEFAULT STACK EXPLODED -->
        <interceptor-ref name="exception">
            <param name="logEnabled">true</param>  
            <param name="logLevel">error</param>  
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="datetime"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="validation">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
    <!-- END OF DEFAULT STACK EXPLODED -->

    <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
    <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
    <interceptor-ref name="params" />
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="exception">
        <param name="logEnabled">true</param>
        <param name="logLevel">warn</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</interceptor-stack>
```

As you can see, you have the Parameters Interceptor called twice, plus side effects could have generated the second call.

Simply remove the `defaultStack` declaration inside your stack, and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: thank you very much! yeah, you're right. After comment `defaultStack`  interceptor , only need call once when click query.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine stacktraces you will see that `params` interceptor is called twice between a `chain` interceptor.

This is because you have used result type `chain`.

The chain result creates a new value stack with the same action bean and populates it from the old stack.

When the chained action is invoked it has a `params` interceptor on the stack.

When `params` interceptor is invoked it populates the action bean from action context parameters.

So you can count two calls for `params` interceptor and one for `chain` interceptor.

Comment: Thanks! but no doubt it is very complicated to clairify this, and does it must have to call three times?

Comment: and I doubt struts  does too many duplication works like this

Comment: If you what to clarify this you need to post the `struts.xml`. No doubt it's not a duplicate, since you have two different actions chained together by the result during the request.

Comment: Thanks! I hve posted `struts.xml`, do you think there are some not necessarily interceptor here and could remove?

Comment: They have **not** used any `chain` result

Comment: @zhuguowei yes you have missed them.

Comment: @AndreaLigios The answer was made before the required artifacts was posted. And here I do not need to poke its belated comments, after reaches you.